# How to send attachment with multiple mails at a time using sendgrid

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid php api to send emails and it's working perfectly with attachment when i am sending one email at a time but when I am sending multiple emails at a time with attachment using sendgrid it is not sending emails anymore.

Here is my code

```
$email->setSmtpapiTos($sent_to)        
  ->setFrom($email_from_addr)
  ->setFromName($presenter_name)
  ->setReplyTo($presenter_email)    
  ->addSubstitution("%messagebody%", $notification_sent_body_arr[$i])
  ->addSubstitution("%messagesubject%", $notification_sent_subject_arr[$i])
  ->setSubject("%messagesubject%")
  ->setHtml("%messagebody%"); 

if($notification_type == 2){ 
  $email->setAttachment($filename)
    ->addHeader('Content-Type', 'text/calendar')
    ->addHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline');
}
```

I am using chunk data. It is working fine without attachment but with attachment it is not working.